# Is there a Windows Briefcase equivalent on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, filesystem, sync

Many people ask what the point of briefcases on Windows is.  Basically, it's a fast and easy way to sync documents between removable storage and your PC (that isn't cloud based).

I keep my school documents on both a flash drive and a directory on my PC at home, just in case.  I frequently edit both, editing the flash drive's files at school when I can't access my home PC, and the ones at home when I'm too lazy to find my flash drive.

When I want to sync the files, I can just plug the drive in and click "Update Briefcase" and files will be deleted, created, or updated as I have changed them in either direction, into or out of the briefcase.

Is there a simple, easy to use equivalent I can use on Ubuntu?

Thank you!

Comment: What about rsync

Comment: I was going to mention rsync, but that would probably get dq-ed b/c it's not a button and doesn't determine which is newer dynamically.  You specify source and destination.  Still you get a +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

**Conduit** is a graphical synchronization tool that is available in the Software Center.

[image: Install via the software center]

Once started there are lots of options to sync different types of items, be it folders, files, Evolution memos, etc. Drag and drop two of the folder categories to the workspace pane. Right-click on each to configure and select appropriate folders, one stored locally and the other one on USB drive.

Set up two way and select **[Ask what to do]** if one item deleted. Then ready to sync. In Preferences, you can set it to start at login. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For cross platform synchronisation, the ever popular [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) is always an options, although I would also look into more open alternatives such as [cloudfs](http://labs.vmware.com/flings/cloudfs).